When is rendering done? React Server Components
How to get a callback function called when RSC MyComponent is done rendering :
// dummy content with delay
async function content() {
    await (new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 4000)));
    return "content";
}

export default function MyComponent() {
    // Arbitrary number of Suspense components rendering dummy content with delay
    return (<>
                <Suspense> {content()} </Suspense>
                <Suspense>
                    {content()}
                    <Suspense> {content()} </Suspense>
                </Suspense>
            </>)
}


1. Before MyComponent's return statement, we can run an async function that will descends the returned result jsx tree, awaiting for each Suspense component as it renders. This works well but maybe there's a more straightforward and builtin way ?
// function to traverse a jsx tree and return its nodes as a flat array
function traverse (jsx) {
    if (jsx === undefined || jsx === null) return undefined;
    // end of branch return the last element
    if (!jsx.props || !jsx.props.children) return jsx;
    // keep traversing the tree
    return jsx.props.children.map((c) => traverse(c)).flat();
}

export default function MyComponent() {
    let result = (<>
                      <Suspense> {content()} </Suspense>
                      <Suspense>
                          {content()}
                        <Suspense> {content()} </Suspense>
                    </Suspense>
                  </>)

    let suspensePromises = traverse(result)
        .filter(e => e.then); // only keep promises

    Promise.all(suspensePromises ).then(() => {
        // callback function here
        console.log("component is done rendering suspenses.");
    })

    // send result to client that will render progressively
    return result;
}

2.  I did not try that yet but maybe another possible way would be to hook React.Component.prototype.componentDidUpdate ? As seen here : React, how to know when a pure function component has been rendered?

My question apply to the server and client side respectively, .1 let us have a callback that run on server-side only.
